# Query de búsqueda, según parte de ID (por teclado)

Tags: java

Para buscar un objeto de una base de datos usando NetBeans uso el siguiente método:

```
    public Tema buscar (String id) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement smt = Conexion.getInstancia().prepareStatement("select temanombre, ejeid, nivid from tema where temaid = ?");
    smt.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery();

    modelo.Tema tema = null;
    while (rs.next()){
        String nombre = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String eje = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String nivel = rs.getString("temanombre");
        tema = new Tema(id, nombre, eje, nivel);

    }
    smt.close();
    return tema;
```

Ahora necesito un método que me permita rescatar el nombre del objeto, según una parte del id, estoy tratando de usar esto, pero está malo:

```
    public String buscarNombre (String id) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement smt = Conexion.getInstancia().prepareStatement("select temanombre, ejeid, nivid from tema where temaid  LIKE '?' AND '%'");
    smt.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery();

    modelo.Tema tema = null;
    while (rs.next()){
        String nombre = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String eje = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String nivel = rs.getString("temanombre");
        tema = new Tema(id, nombre, eje, nivel);

    }
    smt.close();
    return tema.getNombre();
}
```

Qué Query debo usar?
De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El caracter comodin (%) es mejor meterlo en el parametro que en la query.

```
public String buscarNombre (String id) throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement smt = Conexion.getInstancia().prepareStatement("select temanombre, ejeid, nivid from tema where temaid  LIKE ? ");
    smt.setString(1, id+"%");
    ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery();

    modelo.Tema tema = null;
    while (rs.next()){
        String nombre = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String eje = rs.getString("temanombre");
        String nivel = rs.getString("temanombre");
        tema = new Tema(id, nombre, eje, nivel);

    }
    smt.close();
    return tema.getNombre();
}
```

Si lo que deseas es que haya comodin por los 2 lados

```
smt.setString(1, "%"+id+"%");
```